# Commandline parameter getting truncated

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

I have simple application that is used to decrypt some value. The app take the decrypted value as a command line parameter, but i am seeing that the value i am passing from the command line is getting truncated.

Here is a very simple snippet

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::cout << argv[1] << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

But when i run this app like this

```
./a.out GFjB5jgaUBVuN5c4fvuHvA==$YzgEE2VvWCMDImzTM9RYNQ==
```

I expect that the value **GFjB5jgaUBVuN5c4fvuHvA==$YzgEE2VvWCMDImzTM9RYNQ==** should be completely read but its getting truncated to **GFjB5jgaUBVuN5c4fvuHvA====**

What is the mistake i am making?

Comment: Strictly speaking, since you are still getting the last two `==`, it is not truly truncated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$NAME` is replaced by the shell with the value of the shell variable `NAME`. You don't a shell variable called `$YzgEE2VvWCMDImzTM9RYNQ`, so that part is replaced with an empty string.

To avoid treating the `$` character as a variable indicator, put the argument in single quotes:

```
./a.out 'GFjB5jgaUBVuN5c4fvuHvA==$YzgEE2VvWCMDImzTM9RYNQ=='
```